# InertiaJS - Laravel, React, Vite Deployment in Vercel

Tags: reactjs, laravel, vite, vercel, inertiajs

I'm currently working on a project using InertiaJS and trying to deploy it on Vercel. I've attempted several solutions without success. Has anyone else had experience deploying an InertiaJS project on Vercel?

Comment: same for me, when i open the deployed domain i get error : ```Unable to locate file in Vite manifest: resources/js/Pages/Home/Index.vue```, which is the homepage.

Comment: Have you built the project? @ahmadkharabsheh

Comment: my problem was solved. maybe this tutorial may help you too https://calebporzio.com/easy-free-serverless-laravel-with-vercel, but still after this configuration u need to set the build command in vercel deployment configuration to build the client side bundle @ahmadkharabsheh

Comment: yeah this one worked for me, but i also had to add additional routes in ```vercel.json``` for vue components to work, glad you were able to get it work